# Having trouble dividing a row in a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

So I'm currently working on a program that implements Gauss-Jordan elimination on a 2D array (matrix) and I am currently having a bit of a stump just trying to get the first row to divide itself by the first pivot:

```
void Gauss(int i, int j, int size, int mat [size][size])
{
    int x = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if(mat[i][j]== mat[i][i]) {
                mat[0][i] = mat[0][i]/mat[i][i];
                mat[i][i] = mat[i][i]/mat[i][i];
                mat[i][j] = mat[i][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are is my original mat:

2  2  4

2  1  7

1  3  5

and here is my mat afterwards:

1  2  0

2  1  7

1  3  1

The program keeps dividing the first row by each of the diagonals. Can someone explain why this is occurring and a HINT as to how to fix it? Also, I don't have to worry about any of the pivots already being 0 because this is part of a much larger project that states it won't contain that.

Comment: `int mat [i][j]){` --> `int mat [size][size]){` ?

Comment: are you sure you want to use `int`s for your matrices?

Comment: You should check if mat[i][i] is 0 first at all (to not divide by 0). Please provide more data about what results you get, and what it should be.

Comment: Yea, I should be using floats. I was trying to see If i could just manipulate a simple matrix composed of even numbers first before moving on to more complicated numbers in my matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
void Gauss(int i, int j, int size, int mat [i][j])
```

to this:

```
void Gauss(int i, int j, int size, int mat [size][size])
```

---

This `mat[i][j] = mat[i][i];` has no usefulness, since it only gets executed when `mat[i][j]== mat[i][i]`.

---

In this kind of applications, people usually use `float` and not `int`, but this is of course is not your direct error.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i missed that.